# SQLITE use other Wildcard characters than % and _

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have vendor supplied names which contain eg 'X' as wildcard characters. IS there a way in SQLITE to search for these terms with 'X' as wildcard character?
So the query would look like
SELECT column WHERE column LIKE 'searchtermXX'
IS this possible?

I tried

```
SELECT column WHERE column LIKE REPLACE('searchtermXX','X','\%' ESCAPE '\')
```

This unfortunately does not work.

Comment: `ESCAPE ''` is not a thing in SQLite. If you remove that part, your code should just work.

Comment: And your query needs a `FROM` clause, of course.

Comment: Using one of the extensions that provide regular expression support is one way.

Comment: @GMB without ESCAPE (and with a FROM of couurse) I get `SQL logic error near "'\%'": syntax error`

Comment: Why are you putting a backslash before the percent sign? Just `REPLACE('searchtermXX', 'X', '%' )`.